# Flip clock is flipping backwards instead of forward

Tags: javascript, css, flipclock

In the given Codepen below, there is a flip clock on the tomato. Currently, the flip clock is counting down correctly, but the actual flippers are flipping backwards, away from the viewer, rather than forwards. I think that the problem may have to do with `z-index` switching, or possibly the fact that some aspect of the transform has been rotated 180deg (most likely the former, as the latter would ostensibly affect the whole clock, not just the shadows of the flippers).

[Here is the link to the Codepen.](https://codepen.io/dankest_of_memes/pen/qjzgXQ)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem.

Your CodePen is currently using the minified version of flipclock.css from https://cdnjs.com/, switching to the full css file should fix your issue.